# Getting Cassandra to use an alternate Java install

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm working on getting a Cassandra instance up and running, but i'm having issues telling Cassandra which Java installation to use. The situation is as follows:

The server has Java 6 installed, and all Java environment variables are pointed to this installation ($JAVA_HOME, etc). This installation is what every other program on the server utilizes right now.

Java 7 is also installed, in a separate location, but is not the version used by default.

I've attempted to dig into the cassandra-env.sh script in $CASS_HOME/conf and the cassandra script in $CASS_HOME/bin, but I haven't had much luck finding a place to specify a different $JAVA_HOME directory. Does anyone have experience with doing this sort of thing with Cassandra?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did finally find this setting:

In the $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin dir, there is a file called cassandra.in.sh, there is a section that looks like this:

```
   # JAVA_HOME can optionally be set here
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk6
```

You can modify this to have Cassandra use a different Java installation.

Comment: Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install Cassandra 3.11, the file was located at `/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/.../share/cassandra/cassandra.in.sh`. Using [SdkMan](https://sdkman.io) to install Java, that is located at `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current`. Updating the `sh` script to point at the current Java worked for me.

Comment: Location of `cassandra.in.sh` on Ubuntu system is `/usr/share/cassandra/cassandra.in.sh`.